# Show different menu items for logged in user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to create a menu-bar in my Rails application to show `Login` when a user is not logged in, and `Logout` plus what actions they have available to them, i.e. `Admin`, `Users`, etc. I attempted to use this code in my application layout (`application.html.haml` in `app/views/layout`)

```
%ul{:class => 'nav'}
%li= link_to 'Home', :root
    - if logged_in?
        %li= link_to 'Logout', logout_url
```

However, it gives me an error stating,

```
NoMethodError in Session#new
undefined method `logged_in?' for #<#<Class:0x007f771bbe0f70>:0x007f771bc6a1a8>
```

I don't need to change anything in the layout other than the menu itself, so I don't want to render different layouts depending on if a user is logged in. Is it possible to show the `logged_in?` method to the `application` layout, or somehow let the layout know if a user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Devise for authentification, the correct method is `user_signed_in?`

Edit :

Controller methods can only be called from controllers.
However, you could store the result of that method in an instance variable.
In your ApplicationController do

```
before_filter :login_check

def login_check
  @logged_in = logged_in?
end
```

Now in your view you can check if @logged_in is true, like this

```
%ul{:class => 'nav'}
%li= link_to 'Home', :root
    - if @logged_in
        %li= link_to 'Logout', logout_url
```

Comment: I'm not using `Devise`, just a custom method named `logged_in?`

Comment: @cacidol where did you define that custom method ?

Comment: `application_controller.rb` in `app/controllers`

Comment: Can you copy the method `logged_in` here?